# Why my WndProc doesn't receive Shell Hook Messages if the app is set as Default Windows Desktop Shell?

Tags: c#, shell, desktop, windows-shell, wndproc

```
    uMsgNotify = WinApi.RegisterWindowMessage("SHELLHOOK");
    WinApi.RegisterShellHookWindow(this.Handle);
```

in my Form constructor

and this in my overrided WndProc:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    IntPtr handle;
    if (m.Msg == uMsgNotify)
    {
        switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
        {
            case WinApi.HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED:
                handle = m.LParam;
                string windowName = GetWindowName(handle);
                MessageBox.Show(windowName+" "+handle.ToString());
                break;
            case WinApi.HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED:
                handle = m.LParam;
                MessageBox.Show(handle.ToString());
                break;
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

So this Win Form Works fine when default windows shell is explorer.exe. I can get all events All created and destroyed windows and their names. When i set my app.exe as defaul windows Shell. It doesn't receive messages.

Do I have to use dll function injection, separate dll file for hooking?
I was trying to get simplier and easier solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`WH_SHELL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#wh_shellhook) documentation explicitly states:

> Note that custom shell applications **do not**
>   receive `WH_SHELL` messages.
>   Therefore, any application that
>   registers itself as the default shell
>   must call the [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
>   function before it (or any other
>   application) can receive `WH_SHELL`
>   messages. This function must be called
>   with `SPI_SETMINIMIZEDMETRICS` and a
>   [`MINIMIZEDMETRICS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724500%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure. Set the
>   **iArrange** member of this structure to
>   ARW_HIDE.

Comment: Thanks Franci, but it took another 3-4 hours testing debuging, googling. The problems were converting WinApi structs and funcs to C# and invoke them in proper order, setting MINIMIZEDMETRICS structure. Anyway now is working perfectly. I used  Cairo Desktop Source Code and this thread:   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/cfaa9f53-8bfd-4a0a-9e9a-4c2b7d47327a

Comment: @nasko7 - I trust you used pinvoke.net to get the right C# definitions for the Win32 APIs and structs, right? :-)